# What is $\left( \frac{t^2}{t^2+2}i+\frac{2}{t^2+2}j+\frac{2t}{t^2+2}k \right) \times \frac{2ti-2tj-(t^2+2)k}{t^2+2}$?

Tags: calculus, arithmetic, frenet-frame

I did

\begin{align}
& \left( \frac{t^2}{t^2+2}i+\frac{2}{t^2+2}j+\frac{2t}{t^2+2}k \right) \times \frac{2ti-2tj-(t^2+2)k}{t^2+2} \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{2t^2i-4tj-2t(t^2+2)k}{(t^2+2)^2} \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{2t^2i-4tj-2t^3k+4tk}{(t^2+2)^2} \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{-4tj+4tk}{(t^2+2)^2}
\end{align}

Is this true?

Comment: How are you getting from the 3rd to the 4th line?  You can't just drop or cancel the $\mathbf i$ term.

Comment: Oops, I thought that the $2t^3k$ cancels it out

Comment: $\mathbf i, \mathbf j, \mathbf k$ are vectors that are independent from each other.  There is no cancelling out across these terms.

Comment: Other than that do the calculations look okay?

Comment: Not really, I have put my calculations in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

$(\frac{t^2}{t^2+2}i+\frac{2}{t^2+2}j+\frac{2t}{t^2+2}k) \times \frac{2ti-2tj-(t^2+2)k}{t^2+2}$

$\frac {1}{(t^2 + 2)^2} ((-2(t^2+2)+4t^2) \mathbf i + (4t^2+t^2(t^2+2))\mathbf j + (-2t^3-4t) \mathbf k)$

$\frac {1}{(t^2 + 2)^2} ((2t^2 - 4) \mathbf i + (t^4+6t^2) \mathbf j -(2t^3+4t) \mathbf k)$

$\frac {2t^2 - 4}{(t^2 +2)^2} \mathbf i + \frac {t^4+6t^2}{(t^2 + 2)^2} \mathbf j - \frac {2t^3+4t}{(t^2 + 2)^2} \mathbf k$

Comment: In the second line I can undestand how you computed the k terms. But I can't how you computer the i and the j terms. For j, it seems like you are multiplying k by j + i by k? 

Is this the determinant method?

Comment: $(a\mathbf i + b\mathbf j + c\mathbf k)\times (p\mathbf i + q\mathbf j + r\mathbf k) = (br-cq) \mathbf i + (cp-ar)\mathbf j + (aq-bp)\mathbf k$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
i\times j & = k = -j\times i \\
j\times k & = i = -k\times j \\
k\times i & = j = - i\times k \\
i \times i & = j \times j = k\times k = 0
\end{align}